# get data from JSON file (with cURL)

Tags: php, json, curl

I would like to trnsform some JSON data to a php array, this is my code:

```
<?php
$obj1=json_decode('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/3.15.5/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json', true);

$championname = $obj1[data][aatrox][name];
echo $championname;
?>
```

The problem is that i don't know how to get the data from http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/3.15.5/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json

How can i make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `file_get_contents()` like this:

```
    $json = file_get_contents('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/3.15.5/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json');
    $obj1 = json_decode($json , true);

    $championname = $obj1['data']['aatrox']['name'];
    echo $championname;
```

Comment: That did indeed work, now i think $obj1['data']['aatrox']['name']; is wrong, because it doesn't gives me the variable. This is the array from http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/3.15.5/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json

Array
(
    [type] => champion
    [format] => standAloneComplex
    [version] => 3.15.5
    [data] => Array
        (
            [Aatrox] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Aatrox
                    [key] => 266
                    [name] => Aatrox
                    [title] => the Darkin Blade

Comment: It is with a capital `A` like this: `$obj1['data']['Aatrox']['name']`

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents` to download a file.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/3.15.5/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json');
$obj1 = json_decode($json, true);
```